# How do I reliably make a lane push by itself?

Tags: league-of-legends

What do I have to do, and when, to make a wave of minions start building up so it pushes a lane by itself?

I am **not** talking about split pushing, where I am constantly in the lane I want pushed.

I want to set up a lane so it starts pushing with a pile of regular minions so I can join my team to siege another lane 5 vs 5 or to do map objectives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes time, and the self control not to kill all those minions ;)
You'll find most answers in this [Lol Forum topic](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=571528)

Long story short, you shall kill only the ennemy's mage minions first. They are the weakest, but they hit the hardest (twice as much as the melee minions if I remember correctly). Your minions will spend quite a bit of time to kill the solid melee minions, just enough time to let the next wave reach them, you'll then have 4-5 minions left in your first wave + the 6 (or 7) of the next wave. If the initial fight is in your part of the map, you may eventually kill the ranged minions of the opposite second wave, in order to build a hardcore minion wave, but it takes time.

Have fun.

Comment: @Hackworth And Soraka is the goddess of giga wave building, by healing your focused minion, and giving him a lot of armor, you'll end up losing NO minion in the first wave